# What is the recommended way to create upper case tables in MySQL in Windows?

Tags: mysql

According to the [MySQL doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html), we cannot use `0` or `2` for the variable `lower_case_table_names` for Windows OS. Using option `1` will create the tables in lower case. So how should we create the tables in upper case exactly?

My MySQL Version - 5.5.24

Answer (score 0):

Leave the config variable `lower_case_table_names` as it is now, and just use uppercase names when creating all your tables:

```
CREATE TABLE MY_UPPERCASE_TABLE(...);
```